# How do I fix an "unknown chipset" error when booting Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot, console

I have a laptop with this hardware:

- intel i5
- nvidia 820m graphics card
- 64bit system with uefi boot

I burned the Arch Linux ISO to USB, and I am getting the option to choose Arch on booting the USB, but its not starting.

Instead I'm getting this error:

[image: unknown chipset error]

Comment: that's a very vague error...

Comment: Fermi is your NVIDIA chipset. Can you disable it in BIOS and try without it?

Comment: @petry tried that, getting different error

Comment: Are you using the latest Arch bootable image?

Comment: Try adding 'nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0' to the boot options.

Comment: Yeah, just add it to the end of the options.

Comment: @teppic it worked, now am able to boot in to arch. pls add it as an answer

Comment: similar for Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/567965/nouveau-error-unknown-chipset-during-startup-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that by default Arch boots up with kernel modesetting for the display (and console), using the open source nouveau driver. It seems that the driver included in this kernel doesn't support your graphics chipset, and rather than fallback, it simply gives you no console display.

To disable kernel modesetting you can edit the boot options in the boot menu and add the following

```
nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0
```

It's possible that it will work with the latest kernel once you update Arch. However, if you install the official nvidia drivers this will not be necessary, as nouveau isn't used any more.

Comment: hey nouveau is used on my ubuntu for nvidia graphics card

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Different kernels, etc. The current Arch kernel is more recent than the latest bootable image, so try updating.

Answer (score -1):

This error can be very misleading, and it has nothing to do with your nVidia chipset.
In many cases its caused by an NTFS partition which was not completely unmounted.
The solution can be turning the Fast startup off in Windows (http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: the image shows Fermi chipset, and my nvidia comes with fermi chipset